# sbt dependencies ignoring version

Tags: scala, sbt, coursier

In my build.sbt files I'm stating that I want to use version 18.9 from a library:

```
val finagleVersion = "18.9.0"
<zip>
lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  <zip>,
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-core" % finagleVersion,
```

but this seems to be ignored when I run sbt with

```
scalacOptions ++= (compilerOptions :+ "-Ylog-classpath"),
```

which outputs all the jars used at compile time. And there I see that for every finagle dependency including core the 19.3 version is used:

```
C:\Users\<me>\.coursier\cache\v1\https\<me>%40<company repo>\artifactory\Central-cache\com\twitter\finagle-core_2.12\19.3.0\finagle-core_2.12-19.3.0.jar
```

Where is this "preference" for the latest versions coming from?

Comment: What is the output of `sbt evicted`? Sounds like another dependency may depend on the other version, causing it to be picked instead.

Answer (score 2):

After using `evicted` and seeing which library overrides the version you want, you can opt to use [dependencyOverrides](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version). For example:

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.twitter" %% "finagle-core" % "18.9.0"
```

You do have to be careful though as the library that depends on Finagle too may require the newer version and break if you use the older version. That is why you should really check first which library is evicting the old version, and validate if it's ok to do so.

Also important, this is a livy-only feature so the override won't be present in the published pom.xml!